# Check an exec is writing to stdin or not in C

Tags: c, stdin, eof

For my program, i have a main file and a helper file, connected by pipes. The main file writes to the helper file through stdin and the helper writes to the main by stdout. the helper file is a child process to the main by a fork, then runs an exec.
How can i have the helper method check if the pipe is closed, when it is reading from what is stdin?
At the moment i'm using the code below, but it just sits in a infinite loop as EOF for stdin is ctrl-D, which will never happen as the main function is only sending strings of data (mostly integers).

```
while (1) {
                read(0, buffer, 20 );
                sscanf(buffer, "%d" , &info.numAgents);
                if (feof(stdin)) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "Handler communication breakdown.\n");
                        exit(4);
                }


        }
```

Comment: Please show the code that sets up the pipes. Looks like you are reading from a wrong stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pipe(7) man page:

> ```
>    If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have
>    been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-
>    of-file (read(2) will return 0).
> ```

Check your read return code.

Comment: Oh, so if i modify my code be like:
If (read(0, buffer, 20) == 0) {
      exit stuff
{
?

Comment: Yes this should work, unless your pipe setup is doing something wrong.